# auto embed the most recent video from youtube playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery

There was a question about to make an auto embed the most recent video from the channel.
I am trying to make auto embed the most recent video from youtube playlist to webpage.

If a new one would be added on the youtube playlist - it would automatically updates on your webpage.

Here is the code I tried, but it does not update for the latest video, possibly I do something wrong.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rI4kdGLaUiQ" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <script>
      var channelID = "UCCTVrRB5KpIiK6V2GGVsR1Q";
      $.getJSON('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Ffeeds%2Fvideos.xml%3Fchannel_id%3D'+channelID, function(data) {
      var link = data.items[0].link;
      var id = link.substr(link.indexOf("=")+1);
      $("#youtube_video").attr("src","https://youtube.com/embed/"+id + "?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0");
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well that's a good start, but can you elaborate more on what the issue is? Is it the wrong video (meaning the id is wrong), does nothing happen (possibly console errors?), what exactly is "not working"?

Comment: I created a fiddle, and seeing it at least show a video. Is it possible you're not getting the right id? https://jsfiddle.net/3c1y701z/

Comment: You can do with youtube v3 api

Comment: @VKys did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're targetting an element with id `youtube_video` but have no element with that id. I tested this locally and saw your issue. Also I added some other code that's better (doing this on document ready).

```
<body>
<iframe id="youtube_video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rI4kdGLaUiQ" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var channelID = "UCCTVrRB5KpIiK6V2GGVsR1Q";
  $.getJSON('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Ffeeds%2Fvideos.xml%3Fchannel_id%3D'+channelID, function(data) {
  var link = data.items[0].link;
  var id = link.substr(link.indexOf("=")+1);
  $("#youtube_video").attr("src","https://youtube.com/embed/"+id + "?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0");
  });
})

</script>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3c1y701z/3/)